# `Incorrect host for API function "files/upload"` error when trying to upload a file by using Dropbox API 2

Tags: curl, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to upload file by using Dropbox API 2.

I could get user info by this command:

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account \
    --header "Authorization: <access token>" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data "null"
```

But with this command I got a error `Incorrect host for API function "files/upload".  You must issue the request to "content.dropboxapi.com".%`

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer <access token>" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
    --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"test\": \"/apitest.txt\", \"mode\": \"overwrite\"}" \
--data-binary @foo.txt
```

`content.dropboxapi.com` returns only `Not Found` json.

How can I upload a file by using Dropbox API 2?

Comment: I think that what you pasted (but with the right host) should work. Can you share the curl command you tried?

Comment: Oh, just noticed you have "test" instead of "path". Be sure to fix that also.

Comment: oh, I should use `content.dropboxapi.com`, instead of `api.dropboxapi.com` and `path` is not a directory name that is created in dropbox folder. Thanks!